# How to do modular arithmetic on power tower?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am struggling to learn modular arithmetic for power towers (tetration). Like for example, how would I go about $$\left[{13^{13^{13^{13^{13^{13^{13^{13}}}}}}}}\right] \bmod (1000)$$ Or for any number n, what do I do?

Comment: Have you attempted the problem yourself?

Comment: I attempted to find the period of 13^n, but I couldn't find one

Comment: I know I need to do something mod (the period)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax commands aren't effective unless they are surrounded by `$` signs.  `$13^{13}$` shows up as $13^{13}$

Comment: Sorry about that. I will edit it right now

Comment: The cool thing about power tower tetration is that past the first half dozen or so exponents, the mod remains fixed, so even infinitely tall power towers have a well-defined mod value. You'll want to use Euler's totient function, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713648/how-to-compute-ab-mod-m) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The powers of $n$ modulo $k$ repeat with some period that is a factor of $\phi(k)$, which is known as [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).  Here the powers of $13$ repeat with a period of $100$. One easy way to calculate that is to make a spreadsheet with $1$ in a cell, then put =mod(up*13,1000) in the cell below and copy down.  Just look until you see $1$. That means you only need to know the stack with one less $13$ modulo $100$.  The powers of $13 \bmod 100$ repeat with period $20$ so you need the stack with two less $13$s $\bmod 20$.  After a few steps you will have period $1$ and don't need to go any farther.  One more step gets you down to $4$

Comment: How do I find the period as 100 without any software? I'll edit my title for hand-only solutions

Comment: I don't know any easy way.  You can just check the factors of $1000$, which are $16$ of them.  You can reduce the number of multiplications by squaring, so checking $2,4,8$ only take one multiply each.  From $4$ you get $5$ with one multiply, then $25$ with two more and so on.  Each multiply is only three by two digits at most, so is rather quick.  I think it is in the range of hand calculation.